# Copying a CFileDialog file

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, mfc, file-copying, cfiledialog

I'm using a CFileDialog dialog box to open a file in my program. When this file gets opened, I'd also like to save a copy of that file into the directory of my program. How can I do this?

This is how I' m  opening the file:

```
CFileDialog fileDlg(TRUE, NULL, NULL, OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY, "All Files (*.*)|*.*||", this);
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The same way that you copy any other file when you know the path. That's all the `CFileDialog` gives you. See here: [In an MFC application, what's the easiest way to copy a file from one directory to another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191980/in-an-mfc-application-whats-the-easiest-way-to-copy-a-file-from-one-directory-t)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file dialog doesn't copy files. After it returns, you get the selected file, then use regular file copy API to copy the file.